# Why Data is not flowing to downstream functions immediately when custom duplex stream is used in the stream pipeline

Tags: node.js, stream, node-streams

I am trying to create a custom duplex stream to understand streams in nodejs. But when I run it the tranform stream in the code is executed only when readable stream ends the stream (`this.push(null)`).

```js
const Stream = require('stream');
const Chance = require('chance');
const chance = new Chance();
let i = 0;
const readableStream = new Stream.Readable({ highWaterMark: 5 })


const customWriteStream = new Stream.Writable({
    write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        console.log(`CustomeWriteStream Called ${chunk}`)
        callback();
    },
    highWaterMark: 30
});

const upperCaseTransform = new Stream.Transform({
    transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        console.log(`upperCaseTransform Called ${chunk}`)
        callback(null, chunk.toString().toUpperCase());
    },
    highWaterMark: 30
});

const lowerCaseTransform = new Stream.Transform({
    transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        console.log(`lower Called ${chunk}`)
        callback(null, chunk.toString().toLowerCase());
    },
    highWaterMark: 30
});

const duplexStream = new Stream.Duplex({
    write: function (chunk, encoding, next) {
        console.log('Calling write in duplex')
        this.push(chunk);
        next();
    },
    read: function (size) {
        console.log('Calling read in duplex');
    },
    highWaterMark: 30
})

readableStream._read = function (size) {
    const data = chance.string({ length: size })
    console.log(`read ${++i}, ${size}, ${readableStream.readableHighWaterMark}`, data)
    if (i == 5) {
        this.push(null);
        return;
    }
    this.push(data);
}

// Stream.pipeline(readableStream, upperCaseTransform, lowerCaseTransform, customWriteStream, (err) => {
//     err && console.error(err);
// });

Stream.pipeline(readableStream, duplexStream, upperCaseTransform, lowerCaseTransform, customWriteStream, (err) => {
    err && console.error(err);
});
```

Current Output

```
read 1, 5, 5 p(xFq
read 2, 5, 5 Nfex2
Calling write in duplex
read 3, 5, 5 gPi]^
Calling write in duplex
read 4, 5, 5 T!7@v
Calling write in duplex
read 5, 5, 5 UwvhE
Calling write in duplex
Calling read in duplex
upperCaseTransform Called p(xFq
lower Called P(XFQ
CustomeWriteStream Called p(xfq
upperCaseTransform Called Nfex2
lower Called NFEX2
CustomeWriteStream Called nfex2
upperCaseTransform Called gPi]^
lower Called GPI]^
CustomeWriteStream Called gpi]^
upperCaseTransform Called T!7@v
lower Called T!7@V
CustomeWriteStream Called t!7@v
```

But If i remove the duplex stream from the pipeline I get

```
read 1, 5, 5 (EUcE
read 2, 5, 5 BM3!h
upperCaseTransform Called (EUcE
lower Called (EUCE
CustomeWriteStream Called (euce
read 3, 5, 5 %!UB8
upperCaseTransform Called BM3!h
lower Called BM3!H
CustomeWriteStream Called bm3!h
read 4, 5, 5 dwer6
upperCaseTransform Called %!UB8
lower Called %!UB8
CustomeWriteStream Called %!ub8
read 5, 5, 5 fJKR]
upperCaseTransform Called dwer6
lower Called DWER6
CustomeWriteStream Called dwer6
```

As we can see all the steps are being executed one after other once data is read, but why when we add duplex stream its only passed to downstream after readable stream completes ?